# Do more people earn BAs or BSs in Linguistics?

Tags: united-states, degree, bachelor, linguistics

I'm interested in the proportion of BAs vs BSs awarded in linguistics in the United States, but it would be interesting to see these numbers for any field really. I haven't been able to find such stats, so even just a link to where these numbers might be found would be very appreciated.

Comment: I imagine this is dependent on the country or even the university in question as not everywhere will award BScs in linguistics for instance. (It still baffles me that in some places you can get a *BA* in physics.)

Comment: @astronaut I mean, the whole system of naming fell to shambles when math, one of the liberal arts, stopped being a BA and become a BS ;-)

Comment: @guifa I never really got why Math used to be classified as an Art field; it'd seem so out-of-place there.  My speculation's been that, historically, it was seen under Cartesian dualism as a non-empirical field, which presumably justified its separation from the natural sciences, engineering, etc..

Comment: @Nat It wasn't classified as a fine art, rather a liberal art. The liberal arts historically included the Trivium (arts of humanities: logic, grammar, rhetoric) and the Quadrivium (scientific arts: music, arithmetic, geometry, and astronomy)

Comment: My school doesn't award ling BSes and I've never heard of a school awarding them (but I haven't looked that comprehensively ...)

Comment: My (perhaps flawed) understand that a BA was supposed to be about studying a field (art or science) for the sake of the field itself, while a BS was supposed to focus more on applied use of that field. In a way, a BA was slightly more geared towards preparation for higher degrees, while BS was targeted toward going directly into industry. But that was just my impression based on the universities I attended.

Answer (score 2):

When I was studying linguistics and trying to decide BA or BS, my professors said the BS was not as common because the majority didn't want to take the additional science based classes required. I do not have specific stats. I received my BA in '98 from U of Utah.